# php curl problem

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to get information of remote file with curl. Problem is that other web-server  is on port 81.

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_PORT , 81);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://98.246.25.185/server_status2.php');
$store = curl_exec ($ch);
echo substr($store, 1);
curl_close ($ch);
?>
```

And as you can see it doesnt work.

Comment: <?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_PORT , 81);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://98.246.25.185/server_status2.php');
$store = curl_exec ($ch);
echo substr($store, 1);
curl_close ($ch);
?>

Comment: @DanSpd : the code is not messaed up by the "stupid script" : you just didn't respect the code-formating specification : on the right of the edit form, there should be a quick reference about the syntax, and a link to the full reference : http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help ;; and in the toolbar of the edit-form, there is an icon with some 0 and 1, which indents code so it is formated.

Comment: Maybe my browser messes it up when I use it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What happens if you specify the port number in the URI ?

What I mean is first remove the `CURLOPT_PORT` line, and, then, modify the `CURLOPT_URL` one to add the port number :

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://98.246.25.185:81/server_status2.php');
```

**Edit after the comment** : I just tryied this portion of code :

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
//curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_PORT , 81);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://98.246.25.185:81/server_status2.php');
$store = curl_exec ($ch);
echo substr($store, 1);
curl_close ($ch);
```

And I get this output :

```
Online Peak: 59
Online: 17
Distributive server: Online
Agent server: Online
```

So, the code seems to be OK.

Are you sure there is not a firewall or anything or your network, that prevents you from doing HTTP requests on port 81 to that server ?

Does it work when you type that URI in your browser ?

Comment: it will keep loading for ever

Comment: I confirm it remains "waiting" forever ^^ Which is generally caused by some network connection not being possible : like if there were some firewall on your network, preventing your first server from connecting to that second server (I've seen that kind of situation of few times, where non-standard port where blocked by hosting providers -- maybe it's the case here ? )

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you're using SELinux or not (e.g. under Centos) but you may need to allow this specific permission (non-typical ports):

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on
```

I would also strongly suggest adding additional configuration options to get any error output from CURL such as:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$curl_errno = curl_errno($ch);
$curl_error = curl_error($ch);
if($curl_errno > 0)
    die("cURL Error ($curl_errno): $curl_error");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your original code works fine for me. Returns:

```
<b>Online Peak: </b>59        <br /><b>Online: </b> 17<br /><b>Distributive server:</b> <font color=green>Online</font><br /><b>Agent server:</b> <font color=green>Online</font><br />
```

Perhaps the port is being blocked by your firewall?

P.S.
The echo in your code is redundant. The `curl_exec` prints the result to the output buffer unless you set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` as `TRUE`.