# PHP cURL sending to port 8080

Tags: php, curl, port

today I am trying to make a curl call to somesite which is listening to port 8080. However, calls like this get sent to port 80 and not 8080 instead:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 8080);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://somesite.tld:8080');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$target_response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

am i missing something here?

Comment: You could try http://somesite.tld:8080 as url.

Comment: i've asked them already and told me it was open. btw, will curl requests default to port 80 if the specified port is locked?

Comment: maybie the page you are trying to connect is checking user agent ?

Comment: if the port is locked, then curl will fail. The remote server redirects the request, try setting CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION to false then see the response.

Comment: And what exactly makes you think they're directed at port 80 instead of port 8080? Are you absolutely certain that the var you specify in CURLOPT_PORT is 8080? Because it *should* work, either setting the port with CURLOPT_PORT and using the URL without port number in CURLOPT_URL, or by specifying the complete URL (including port) in CURLOPT_URL, without using CURLOPT_PORT.

Comment: @wimvds: because the remote server also listens to port 80 but outputs a different response. Say port 80 replies 1 and port 8080 replies 0. The reply I am expecting is supposed to be 0 but instead i get a 1.

@kamil & arvin: i will try.

Comment: For debugging such issues you could add curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1) and see the debugg info in web server error log

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933505/php-curl-problem

Answer (score 4):

Just a note, I've had this issue before because the web host I was using was blocking outbound ports aside from the standard 80 and 443 (HTTPS). So you might want to ask them or do general tests. In fact, some hosts often even block outbound on port 80 for security.

Comment: How exactly is 990 standard?

Comment: Corrected it to 443. Sorry was working with FTPS that day and wrote the wrong number.

Answer (score 1):

Simple CURL `GET` request: (Also added json/headers if required, to make your life easier in need)

```
<?php
$chTest = curl_init();
curl_setopt($chTest, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com:8080/?query=Hello+World");
curl_setopt($chTest, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8', 'Accept: application/json'));
curl_setopt($chTest, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($chTest, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$curl_res_test = curl_exec($chTest);
$json_res_test = explode("\r\n", $curl_res_test);

$codeTest = curl_getinfo($chTest, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($chTest);
?>
```

Example `POST` request:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.com:8080');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8', 'Accept: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"Hello" : "World", "Foo": "World"}');
// Set timeout to close connection. Just for not waiting long.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

$curl_res = curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

*Charset* is not a required HTTP header and so are the others, the important one is **Content-Type**.

For the examples I used JSON MIME type, You may use whatever you want, take a look at the link:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type

Make sure that the `php_curl.dll` extension is enabled on your php, and also that the ports are open on the target serve.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First check that you're able to connect using something other than PHP's horrible Curl syntax:

- [Chrome's Postman is easy to use](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) if you're on your local machine,

else look at using (for linux users)

- curl somesite:8080
- wget -qO- somesite:8080

Once you've established you can connect, then you can go about the horrible business of using PHP Curl. There are wrappers, but they're flaky that I've found.

Both Curl, Wget or similar can be very easily configured to use GET and POST methods. It's not advisible, but for more than one complicated operation using Curl I've simply given up trying to configure PHP's library correctly and simply dropped to the command line.

*THERE ARE SECURITY IMPLICATIONS.* You need to take great care to ensure that anything you give it, particularly if it's from a form or an external source, is appropriately escaped.

```
<? 

//Strip out any possible non-alpha-numeric character for security

$stringToSend = preg_replace('[^a-zA-Z]', '', $stringToSend);

$return = shell_exec("curl -X POST -d $stringToSend http://example.com/path/to/resource");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your web server is misconfigured.  The code you provided works for me.

Also, your code can be simpler.  Just put the URI into the init call and drop the `CURLOPT_PORT` and `CURLOPT_URL` lines:

`$ch = curl_init('http://somesite.tld:8080');`

Comment: Yes, this works, but it's not necessarily any "simpler".  It saves you one line, but at the cost of readability and extensibility.

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP cURL to make a request to port 8080 on a server

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 8080);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://somesite.tld:8080');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$target_response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
       
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://somesite.tld:8080');
```

Answer (score 0):

Maby you can use
--local-port [-num]

Set a preferred number or range of local port numbers to use for the connection(s). Note that port numbers by nature are a scarce resource that will be busy at times so setting this range to something too narrow might cause unnecessary connection setup failures. (Added in 7.15.2)

Source: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--ftp-pasv

Answer (score -1):

try this option for curl

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY,"localhost:8080");
```

or use this

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY,"yourservername:8080");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "your-domain-name");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch); `
?>
```