# Problems with fetchin JSON data from URL on port 88

Tags: php, json, curl, hosting, php-curl

I have URL for IPTV that produces JSON result.

The URL is ( it's only 24 hour line so it will expire before anyone does any harm )

```
http://mytv-extra.com:88/player_api.php?username=4240670294&password=0301902562&action=get_live_streams&category_id=3045
```

When viewing it in browser it shows you the JSON result which is something like this

```
0   
num 1
name    "##### PL -  POLONIA#####"
stream_type "live"
stream_id   400160541
stream_icon "https://lo1.in/pol/flg.png"
epg_channel_id  null
added   "1620254399"
is_adult    null
category_id "3045"
custom_sid  "3045"
tv_archive  0
direct_source   ""
tv_archive_duration 0
1   
num 2
name    "PL - TVP 4K"
stream_type "live"
stream_id   117574
stream_icon "https://lo1.in/pol/tvp.png"
epg_channel_id  "tvp.pl"
added   "1594210172"
is_adult    null
category_id "3045"
custom_sid  "3045"
tv_archive  0
direct_source   ""
tv_archive_duration 0`
```

but when writing cURL for it to fetch the results i get this

> Array ( [url] => http://mytv-extra.com:88/player_api.php?username=4240670294&password=0301902562&action=get_live_streams&category_id=3045 [content_type] => [http_code] => 0 [header_size] => 0 [request_size] => 0 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 1.025351 [namelookup_time] => 0.005573 [connect_time] => 0 [pretransfer_time] => 0 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 0 [speed_download] => 0 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] => -1 [upload_content_length] => -1 [starttransfer_time] => 0 [redirect_time] => 0 [redirect_url] => [primary_ip] => [certinfo] => Array ( ) [primary_port] => 0 [local_ip] => [local_port] => 0 [http_version] => 0 [protocol] => 0 [ssl_verifyresult] => 0 [scheme] => [appconnect_time_us] => 0 [connect_time_us] => 0 [namelookup_time_us] => 5573 [pretransfer_time_us] => 0 [redirect_time_us] => 0 [starttransfer_time_us] => 0 [total_time_us] => 1025351 ) Curl error: Failed to connect to mytv-extra.com port 88 after 1025 ms: Couldn't connect to server

This is my code

```
<?php
$url = "http://mytv-extra.com:88/player_api.php?username=4240670294&password=0301902562&        action=get_live_streams&category_id=3045";

ch = curl_init();

// Set the URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

// Set other cURL options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

// Set custom headers, including Access-Control-Allow-Credentials
$headers = [
'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/119.0',
'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true',
];

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

// Execute cURL session and fetch the response
$response = curl_exec($ch);

// Get cURL information for debugging
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
print_r($info);

// Check for cURL errors
if ($response === false) {
echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
} else {
echo $response;
}

// Close cURL session
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

I have succesfully created cURL for different URLS just not this one, I have tried everything i could and been Online since 6am to find answers, even AI cannot help. Spoke to Provider and they do not restrict anything

Comment: Maybe you have to select port 88 with `CURLOPT_PORT`?

Comment: tried that with `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 88);` , nothing :(

Comment: unable to verify stated problem. The above however does have a typo - it is `ch = curl_init();` rather than `$ch = curl_init();`

Comment: I tried it with my own code and noted that the API responded badly to the spaces you have in the URL. When I removed the spaces it worked, with my own code, not yours.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, can you point me in the right direction of what I have done wrong? I would appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

This bit of code works for me:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$apiUrl = 'http://mytv-extra.com:88/player_api.php?username=4240670294&password=0301902562&action=get_live_streams&category_id=3045';

$ch = curl_init($apiUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

if ($response === FALSE) {
    $error = curl_error($ch);
    echo 'Error retrieving data: ' . $error;
} else {
    $data = json_decode($response, TRUE);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($data);
    echo '</pre>';
}

curl_close($ch);
```

Note that I removed the spaces from the URL. With the spaces in it I get an error message.

The output looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [num] => 1
            [name] => ##### PL -  POLONIA#####
            [stream_type] => live
            [stream_id] => 400160541
            [stream_icon] => https://lo1.in/pol/flg.png
            [epg_channel_id] => 
            [added] => 1620254399
            [is_adult] => 
            [category_id] => 3045
            [custom_sid] => 3045
            [tv_archive] => 0
            [direct_source] => 
            [tv_archive_duration] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [num] => 2
            [name] => PL - TVP 4K
            [stream_type] => live
            [stream_id] => 117574
            [stream_icon] => https://lo1.in/pol/tvp.png
            [epg_channel_id] => tvp.pl
            [added] => 1594210172
            [is_adult] => 
            [category_id] => 3045
            [custom_sid] => 3045
            [tv_archive] => 0
            [direct_source] => 
            [tv_archive_duration] => 0
        )
      ...............
```

Comment: Then I'm doing something wrong. I have tried your code and got `Error retrieving data: Failed to connect to mytv-extra.com port 88 after 1055 ms: Couldn't connect to server`

Comment: @AICoding As you probably know, there can be many reasons why a connection cannot be made. Do you, or your hosting provider, use some kind firewall? You could simply have been blocked by the API. And there are probably more possible causes.

Comment: You mentioned you have removed spaces in the URL; I apologise for sounding daft, but which areas? I cannot see any spaces.

Comment: @AICoding The URL, in your question, looks like this: `&password=0301902562&    <... lots of spaces ...>    action=get_live_streams`. I suspect that is a typo in the question, and not present in the code you actually use.

Comment: @AICoding Perhaps you can glee a bit more information about the problem you're having from the HTTP error code? Simply add `echo 'HTTP code: . curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);` after the cURL execution.

Comment: So, it will be GoDaddy blocking it. Then, I will try other servers. Thank You

Comment: @AICoding OK, it's GoDaddy. Yes, many cheap (?) hosting providers block a lot of ports.

Comment: @KIKO is this a suitable duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/q/6289878/2943403  Should this new question be closed as cannot reproduce?

Comment: @mickmackusa Yes, it's more-or-less a duplicate of that, but I also voted to close it as non-reproducible. It seems that AICoding has lost interest, and is not going to give any further information/feedback.