# Unable to replicate GET request from web browser

Tags: google-chrome, http, curl, devtools

I'm trying to replicate a request from Chrome browser.
When I open url https://ticket.bolshoi.ru/shows there is a GET request to https://ticket.bolshoi.ru/api/v1/client/shows witch returns json.
I copied the cURL request from DevTools. Here's what I get:

```
curl 'https://ticket.bolshoi.ru/api/v1/client/shows' \
  -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' \
  -H 'Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Cookie: skipped for security reason' \
  -H 'Referer: https://ticket.bolshoi.ru/shows' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin' \
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/118.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="118", "Google Chrome";v="118", "Not=A?Brand";v="99"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"' \
  --compressed
```

But when I run this command in my bash shell I get an html page in response instead of json.
Why does it happen? How to replicate the request?

**Updated**
Here's the output if I add `-Lkv` key to the `curl` command

```
    *   Trying 185.169.155.232:443...
    * Connected to ticket.bolshoi.ru (185.169.155.232) port 443 (#0)
    * ALPN, offering h2
    * ALPN, offering http/1.1
    * successfully set certificate verify locations:
    *  CAfile: /Users/xxx/opt/anaconda3/ssl/cacert.pem
    *  CApath: none
    * TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
    * TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
    * TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
    * TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
    * TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
    * TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
    * TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
    * TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
    * SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    * ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
    * Server certificate:
    *  subject: CN=ticket.bolshoi.ru
    *  start date: Oct 11 23:02:07 2023 GMT
    *  expire date: Jan  9 23:02:06 2024 GMT
    *  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=R3
    *  SSL certificate verify ok.
    > GET /shows HTTP/1.1
    > Host: ticket.bolshoi.ru
    > Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
    > Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
    > Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
    > Cache-Control: no-cache
    > Connection: keep-alive
    > Cookie: spid=xxx; lang=xxx; sails.sid=xxx; spsc=xxx
    > Pragma: no-cache
    > Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
    > Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
    > Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
    > Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
    > Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
    > User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/118.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
    > sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="118", "Google Chrome";v="118", "Not=A?Brand";v="99"
    > sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
    > sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"
    > 
    * TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
    * TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
    * old SSL session ID is stale, removing
    * Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
    < HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    < Server: nginx
    < Date: Wed, 15 Nov 2023 19:09:06 GMT
    < Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    < Connection: keep-alive
    < Keep-Alive: timeout=15
    < access-control-allow-origin: *
    < cache-control: no-cache
    < expires: Wed, 15 Nov 2023 19:0905 GMT
    < pragma: no-cache
    < content-type: text/html
    < X-SP-CRID: xxx:1
    < 
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    ...
</html>
* Connection #0 to host ticket.bolshoi.ru left intact
```

**UPDATED 2**.
Here are some screenshots from web browser:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Maybe the answers/comments in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77465413/problems-with-fetchin-json-data-from-url-on-port-88 will give you some ideas. Good luck.

Comment: Can you add the option `-Lkv`, to get more details (and follow any redirection, with the `-L`)?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Updated my question

Answer (score 5):

The verbose output of your `curl` command confirms a successful connection to `ticket.bolshoi.ru` on port 443, which means there is no issue with the basic connectivity.

The request headers seem to be appropriately set. However, the `Accept` header is set to accept HTML (`text/html`), XML, images, and other types but not explicitly JSON. That could be why the server is responding with an HTML page rather than a JSON response.

The response headers indicate that the server is responding with a content type of `text/html`, which matches the HTML response you are getting instead of JSON.

So try and change the `Accept` header in your cURL request to explicitly ask for JSON.
For example: `-H 'Accept: application/json'`. That informs the server that you are expecting a JSON response.

Assuming the URL in your cURL command (`https://ticket.bolshoi.ru/api/v1/client/shows`) is the correct endpoint for obtaining JSON data, an updated version of your cURL command would be:

```bash
curl 'https://ticket.bolshoi.ru/api/v1/client/shows' \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Cookie: [Your Cookie Data]' \
  -H 'Referer: https://ticket.bolshoi.ru/shows' \
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/118.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' \
  -Lkv
```

---

> Tried this with no success. The response is still an HTML page.

If the same URL returns JSON when accessed via a browser, consider that the browser might be sending additional session data or cookies that are not included in your cURL command. Sometimes, APIs deliver different content based on session-specific data. If you have not already, try copying all the cookies from the browser request and including them in your cURL command.

The server might differentiate between requests made by a browser (which typically can handle HTML and JavaScript) and those made by non-browser clients like cURL (which typically expect raw data like JSON). That differentiation can be based on headers other than `Accept`, such as `User-Agent`. Try changing the `User-Agent` in your cURL command to mimic different browsers and see if the response changes.

Use the network inspector in your browser's developer tools to examine the exact request being made when accessing the URL. That can provide insights into any differences between the browser request and your cURL command.
Make sure all headers sent by the browser are replicated in your cURL request, not just the `Accept` header. That includes cookies, user-agent, and any other headers that might influence the server's response.

If the page at `https://ticket.bolshoi.ru/shows` executes JavaScript to fetch JSON data, the cURL command would not replicate this behavior, as it does not execute JavaScript. That can be especially relevant if the JSON data is loaded dynamically via JavaScript after the initial page load.

---

The screenshots you provided show the successful browser request to `https://ticket.bolshoi.ru/api/v1/client/shows` which returns JSON, as indicated by the `Content-Type` response header being `application/json;charset=UTF-8`.

It also shows that the server is using `gzip` content-encoding. Make sure `curl` can handle the gzip response by using `--compressed`.

The response headers indicate `no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate` and `keep-alive`. While `curl` by default does not cache, ensuring connection persistence with `-H 'Connection: keep-alive'` may reflect the browser behavior more accurately.

Servers can serve different content based on the `User-Agent` string. Match the `User-Agent` from the browser request in your `curl` command if not already doing so.

If there are cookies involved in the browser session that are not present in your `curl` command, this might be necessary for the server to respond correctly. You can try to include all the cookies from the browser's request in your `curl` command.

Although not shown in the screenshots, sometimes servers check the `Referer` and `Origin` headers to serve requests. If your browser request includes these, you should also include them in your `curl` command.

Here is a `curl` command template you can modify to include all relevant headers from the browser request:

```bash
curl 'https://ticket.bolshoi.ru/api/v1/client/shows' \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' \
  -H 'Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Cookie: [all cookies from browser]' \
  -H 'Host: ticket.bolshoi.ru' \
  -H 'Referer: [referer from the browser]' \
  -H 'User-Agent: [user-agent from the browser]' \
  -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' \
  --compressed \
  -Lkv
```

Replace the placeholders (e.g., `[all cookies from browser]`, `[referer from the browser]`, `[user-agent from the browser]`) with the actual values from the browser request.
The `-L` flag will follow redirects, `-k` will ignore SSL validation (use with caution), and `-v` will give verbose output for debugging.

Comment: Tried this with no success. The response is still an html page.

Comment: @StuffHappens That is why I was assuming/asking if that endpoint does return JSON. Do you confirm that https://ticket.bolshoi.ru/api/v1/client/shows returns JSON in a browser?

Comment: I added screenshots of web browser where you can see that the response is json. I copied the request from Chrome dev tools and it copies all the headers (Accept, User-Agent, ect.) and all the cookies. So I'm sure, that headers in web browser request and cURL request are the same. I'm out of ideas why the result might be different.

Comment: @StuffHappens OK. I have edited the answer to address your comment. You might already have included most of what I mentioned, but, just in case, double-check those options.

Comment: Are you sure @StuffHappens you have used `Cookie: [all cookies from browser]` header with proper cookies from your browser?