# PHP Curl on 81 port

Tags: php, curl, xampp, port

I have locally set 2 Apache Server on Port 80 and port 81 using XAMPP. Iam successfully able to access them through my browser. Currently the URL can be accessed at

```
http://27.4.198.225/ncmsl/check.php
```

and

```
http://27.4.198.225:81/ncmsl/check.php.
```

When I try to write a simple curl code for them

```
$ch=curl_init();                    
$url = "http://27.4.198.225/ncmsl/check.php";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

It works perfectly fine for server at port 80 but doesn't work for server at port 81, i.e.

```
$ch=curl_init();                    
$url = "http://27.4.198.225:81/ncmsl/check.php";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

What could be the possible reason? I have tried using CURLOPT_PORT but that also doesn't work

These URL are LIVE URL. Can anybody check whether they are successfully able to access them using thei own CURL code on their own network

Comment: maybe the port is blocked for php, do you have apparmor installed?

Comment: @Hawili Sorry I am using windows so no apparmor. But I think if I am able to access the port through browser then it should not be blocked. Anyways how can I check that in windows

Comment: check out this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1933514/718224

Comment: @AdvaitAmin I did had a look at that URL but still I could not get the curl to work through. These URLS are live URL. Can anybody else access these URL using CURl

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_PORT , 81);
```

**Update code:-**

see this URL:- [php curl problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933505/php-curl-problem)

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://27.4.198.225:81/ncmsl/check.php');
$store = curl_exec ($ch);
echo substr($store, 1);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: As I stated in my question I tried using CURLOPT_PORT but that also doesn't work. These URLS are live URL. Can anybody else access these URL using CURL

Comment: AdvaitAmin Just referred me to the same URL, and I was not able to access the URL through CURL using the same code. But if you are able to do that with you above mentioned code, means I have some problem with my client network which is blocking port 81

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at **CURLOPT_PORT** in the manual for [curl_setopt()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

Comment: As I stated in my question I tried using CURLOPT_PORT but that also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use this one for specify port,

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 81);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']);
```