# PHP - CURLOPT_PROXYPORT issue

Tags: php, curl

I am so confused about my cURL script requesting the target page "facebook.com" for example, with the same port as the proxy.
example: 
proxy is: 178.215.111.70:9999 . a cURL error says:

```
Failed connect to facebook.com:9999; Connection timed out
```

I see  that it tries to connect to facebook using the poxy's port: 9999

Here is my code:

```
    <?php
$curl = curl_init("https://facebook.com");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://www.facebook.com');
if ($var) {
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "test");
}
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,9999999); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, '178.215.111.70');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, '9999');

$result['exe'] = curl_exec($curl);
$result['err'] = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);

echo $result['err'];
echo $result['exe'];
?>
```

Comment: Here you go. I hope this helps:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/12296727/4830549

Comment: @BenLewisWatson unfortunately that didn't work, can you try it on your server and see if it's the same ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem.
It was a problem in the server only. When i tried the SAME script in another server it worked 100% fine

So always make sure of the configuration in your server when you face a problem like this.