# Specify outgoing port in Curl

Tags: php, curl, networking, port, firewall

Dears,

I am trying to do a php curl call from an APACHE Server, but I need to specify that the request should only go (outbound) from a specific port.

Or at least know the range of the outgoing ports used by Apache. Because the destination server sits behind a strict firewall which allows only one IP and one specific port to pass through.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12296606/php-curl-on-81-port

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this.
i think this option CURLOPT_LOCALPORT is what you're looking for

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, [destinationport]);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_LOCALPORT, [sourceport]);

$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);      
print($output);
```

Comment: Just note that if you limit the local port to a single fixed number, the failure rate might be a bit high since chances are it is used already. Using a range there might work better...

Comment: Yep, its true, tried multiple concurrent requests, only 1 reaches its destination. Is there any way for me to know the full range of ports that the Apache server uses by default.